# Why can't I return an array of type double in a method of type double?

Tags: java, arrays, double

Why does this not work?

I'm trying to create an array of type `double` called `s`. Then parsing through some text looking for the keyword "Range:", then adding the next two doubles that come next in the text. My problem is when I try and return this array.

```
public double[] getDaysRange() {

    double[] s = new double[2];
    Scanner parse = new Scanner(stripped);

    while(parse.hasNext()) {
        if(parse.next().equals("Range:")) {

            while(!parse.hasNextDouble()) {

                parse.next();

            }

                s[1] = parse.nextDouble();        //changed these to 0 and 1

                while(!parse.hasNextDouble()) {

                    parse.next();

                }

                s[2] = parse.nextDouble();     //changed to 1

                return s;

        }
        //Moved return s here
    }
```

Edit:
The error I'm getting is "This method must return a result of type double[]"

I moved "return s;" to the bottom and changed my indices but I'm still getting this error.

You can use stripped = "Range:   28.65  -  63.72     "; as an example of what I'm trying to parse.

Comment: Move `return s` to the bottom of the method, as the last statement...

Comment: What is the *exact* error message? Read it. Search for it. (And *always include it in questions*.)

Comment: You have not mentioned your problem itself .

Comment: Arrays are 0-indexed, i.e. the first element is `s[0]`. You can't access `s[2]` if the array only has 2 elements.

Comment: I moved return s down to the bottom and changed the indices but am still getting the error. It reads "This method must return a result of type double[]"

Comment: Assuming correct indentation, the described move of `return s;` leaves it inside the loop. The compiler has to allow for the possibility that `parse.hasNext()` is initially false, so no iterations are executed. You need to decide what to return in that situation and return it after the closing brace of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Make `return s` the last statement

```
public double[] getDaysRange() {

    double[] s = new double[2];
    Scanner parse = new Scanner(stripped);

    while (parse.hasNext()) {
        if (parse.next().equals("Range:")) {

            while (!parse.hasNextDouble()) {
                parse.next();
            }

            s[0] = parse.nextDouble();
            while (!parse.hasNextDouble()) {
                parse.next();
            }

            s[1] = parse.nextDouble();
            // return s; // Not here...
        }
    }
    return s; // Here
}
```

This will ensure that...

1. You get rid of the error message and
2. You return the entire array, not just what was first read...

The problem you now have, is knowing in advance how many elements you might have to read...

If you are only interested in the first two values, you could break the loop

```
//...
s[1] = parse.nextDouble();
// return s; // Not here...
break;
```

This will move you out of the loop and process what ever comes after it (namly the `return` statement).

If you're interested in ALL possible values, you will need to either use a `java.util.List` or pre-seed the file with the number of expected values or pass the expected number of values to the method...

Comment: s[1] should be s[0] and s[2] should be s[1]

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha Really should stop copying and pasting peoples code :P

Answer (score 2):

You can but your method should return a `double` array through all the logical exits of your method. So you need to have

```
        return s;
```

outside of your top-level while loop also.